# jQuery mobile cascading dropdown list do not update properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I'm using cascading drop down lists in my MVC application, and it works fine.

I have added the jQuery mobile library to make it look better in mobile devices browser and I have kind of bug.

An example:

if I choose first time Chevrolet it populate child drop down with Chevrolet models. - as expected

if I choose second time another make I still see the models from previous make, but if I select it I see the new model. It looks like it cashing the models from previous make.

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select#Makes').change(function () {
            getModels();
        });
    });

    function getModels() {

        var make = $('#Makes').val();
        var myselect2 = $("select#Models");
        myselect2[0].selectedIndex = 3;
        myselect2.selectmenu("refresh");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/CarService.asmx/Models",
            data: "{makeId: '" + make + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {


                var models = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $('#Models').attr('disabled', false).removeOption(/./); //.addOption('', ' -- Select Model -- ');
                var select = document.getElementById("Models");
                for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {

                    var val = models[i];
                    var text = models[i];

                    $('select#Models').addOption(val, text, true);
                }

                var myselect = $("select#Models");
                myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
                myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
            }
        });

    }

@Html.DropDownList("Makes", "Please select make")
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Models, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "value", "text"), "Select a Model", new { id = "Models" })
```

Comment: The bug I see only if I use jQuery mobile framework. Dialog window with child items doesn't refresh properly. first time it works. second time I see child items from previous selected parent item. Without jquery mobile cascading dropdown lists work fine

Comment: try refreshing the content after loading: $("select#Models").selectmenu('refresh');